# Rails 6 and Jquery plugin error: $(...).validate is not a function

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, webpack, jquery-validate, yarnpkg

I'm getting the following error `$(...).validate is not a function` while trying to use [jquery-validation](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/package/jquery-validation) in rails 6.

The steps I did to use the library were

1. Add jquery jquery-validation bootstrap popper expose-loader all through Yarn
2. Define jQuery in environment.js
3. Expose Jquery in environment.js
4. Import jquery.validate in application.js
5. Import custom js ("../pages/form-validation") for validation rules on form
6. Create a form

I did the same to use jquery-steps and it worked perfectly. What am I missing?

**environment.js**

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
}))

environment.loaders.append('jquery', {
    test: require.resolve('jquery'),
    use: [{
        loader: 'expose-loader',
        options: '$',
    }, {
        loader: 'expose-loader',
        options: 'jQuery',
    }],
})

module.exports = environment
```

**application.js**

```
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You"re encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it"ll be compiled.
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("channels")


//Dependencias globales
import "bootstrap"
import "../globals/off-canvas"
import "../globals/hoverable-collapse"
import "../globals/misc"
import "../globals/settings"



// Componentes externos
import flatpickr from "flatpickr";
import "flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css"
import "jquery-steps/build/jquery.steps"
import "jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate"

//Componentes de proleague

// JS especifico para ciertas páginas
import "../pages/wizard-forms"
import "../pages/datepicker"
import "../pages/form-validation"
```

**form-validation.js** (custom js for form validation)

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
    'use strict';
    $(function() {
        // validate signup form on keyup and submit
        $("#match-form").validate();
    });
})
```

With all this I'm getting a $(...).validate not defined

[image]

Also, I tried exposing Jquery through the require('expose-loader?$!jquery') in application.js approach and I'd still get the error, but if I called the function directly on the console, it'd get recognized

[image: Console Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out what was the problem and it was my environment.js, while I was exposing jquery as resolve(jquery) and as jquery/src/jquery in my ProvidePlugin, it was causing my app to load Jquery twice, thus, preventing jquery-validate to work properly

So I resolved the problem by changing

```
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
}))
```

to this

```
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
}))
```

I had tried doing this before, but since I wasn't using expose-loader by then, it wouldn't work.

Another solution that I found online (but not applicable to this problem) is when Yarn loads 2 different dependencies, in that case, yarn-deduplicate on yarn.lock is the way to go

Comment: This solved my problem I was struggling with for last 4 months and no proper help is available. I recommend to write an article on this problem.