# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function in rails 6 webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, webpack-4, ruby-on-rails-6

Using ruby 2.7.1p83, Rails 6.0.3.2 with webpack and yarn

installed jquery-validation for validating password update form:

package.json file is as:

> ```
> {
>       "name": "garment_customizer_react",
>       "private": true,
>       "dependencies": {
>         "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.10.4",
>         "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.1",
>         "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0-alpha",
>         "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0-alpha",
>         "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0-alpha",
>         "@rails/webpacker": "4.2.2",
>         "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
>         "huebee": "^2.1.0",
>         "jquery": "^3.5.1",
>         "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
>         "jquery-ui-dist": "^1.12.1",
>         "jquery-validation": "^1.19.2",
>         "jquery.easing": "^1.4.1",
>         "owl.carousel": "^2.3.4",
>         "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
>         "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
>       },
>       "version": "0.1.0",
>       "devDependencies": {
>         "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
>       }
>     }
> ```

script file is as:

> ```
> <script>
>     $(document).ready(function () {
>         $("#form1").validate({
>                 rules: {
>                     user_password: {
>                         required: true, minlength: 5
>                     },
>                     user_confirmation_password: {
>                         required: true, equalTo: "#user_password", minlength: 5
>                     }
>                 }, messages: {
>                     password: " Enter Password",
>                     confirmpassword: " Enter Confirm Password Same as Password"
>                 }
>
>             }
>         );
>     });
> </script>
> ```

getting this error in browser console:

```
> readyException.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validate is not a
> function
>     at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (settings:197)
>     at mightThrow (deferred.js:97)
>     at process (deferred.js:139)
```

But I have already imported jquery and its validation file here as inside pack/uploader.js:

```
import "jquery";
import "jquery-validation";
import "popper.js";
import "bootstrap";
import "jquery-ui";
import 'jquery.easing';
import './x3dom'
import '../stylesheets/assets_uploaders_layout.scss';
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all";
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css";
import '../stylesheets/x3dom.css';
```

any idea how to resolve it.
environment.js file:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require("webpack");
environment.plugins.append(
    "Provide",
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
        jquery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
        Popper: ["popper.js", "default"]
    })
);
module.exports = environment;
```

Comment: can you please show your **environment.js** file ?

Comment: updated answer with environment.js file

Comment: Can you check this, may be helpful to you :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62097010/rails-6-and-jquery-plugin-error-validate-is-not-a-function